# How to mass apply No Access to all folders but one for a specific user account only?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, user-account

*(This is just experimenting for educational purposes.)*

I'm the admin of the computer and I have SIP disabled. I wish to imitate iOS restrictions on macOS by prohibiting access (to one other specific user account, not me) to **all** directories except for '**Downloads**' of their equivalent '**Users**' folder.

Yes, the apps they launch can freely read/write from/to '**Library**' and other system-related files as they normally would, but the user just never gets to access those directories (pretty much like iOS minus the sandboxed app-data)

When using Finder (or any other file browser) they can only access their Downloads folder.

Managing their system (installing/uninstalling apps etc.) is of lesser importance as I, the admin, can do it for them when asked.

I think I can implement this by applying a '**No Access**' rule to their user account for all directories, which attaches a red flag icon to the folder and does not allow one to access it when clicked.

Instead of going through every single folder to do this with `cmd+I`, can I do this with Terminal for all directories minus 'Downloads'?

Comment: You'll have to disable permissions for the current user. Using `Terminal` with the `chmod` command. It would mean doing something like `chmod u-rw Documents Music Pictures Movies <any-folder>`. The `u-rwx` tells the command to remove read/write/execute access to the directory only for the user. To add back any specific permission for the user, you would use `chmod u+...` where `...` is among `r` `w` `x`. Does it help ? More on [permissions and groups](https://mason.gmu.edu/~montecin/UNIXpermiss.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ok, so I just opened Terminal from my admin account, and the user account I'm talking about is: `testuser01`. What is the *exact* command(s) I need to type, in order to achieve what I asked for in the OP?

Comment: `man chmod` might be helpful here.

Comment: Do you mean you also want to forbid **read** access to default directories outside of the user's folder (for instance denying reading `/System`) ? That might prove impossible (unless it causes glitches to the whole system). Also, what about folders created after the initial configuration by 3rd party programs, such as hidden folders (like `~/.dropbox` for instance) ? changing their permissions would require work *after* the initial config. Is that also part of what you want ? (otherwise the user could still `Cmd+Maj+.` to show hidden stuffs.

Comment: Yes, `/System` too. Everything. Everything but their `Downloads` folder. They interact (i.e., read/write) with **all** necessary directory assets of the computer (system or not) that their normal app usage requires, but they have no access to them when using a file browser. Exactly like iOS, you can run any app you like but when you open the Files app you only get to see `Downloads` and `iCloud`. The apps you use interact with all system assets, just in the background; you don't get to browse them (at least not without a jailbreak). The show/hide hidden files shortcut wouldn't solve this.

Comment: Why do you need to do it this way?

Comment: @sfxedit As stated in OP, to imitate iOS limiting you from accessing any folder other than Downloads

Comment: I meant WHY do you want to do that? What is the goal - A normal restricted user account can't really do anything much. Why does it matter if they can access other directories in the Home directory? And why did you think disabling SIP will help you here? I ask because perhaps there is an easier way to meet your goal than the idea you have described.

Comment: @sfxedit Initially inspired by a relative who asked me if I could bring a completely minimalist/iOS feel to their Mac, by utilizing Launchpad/Dock as the only way to launch apps (a la iPhone home screen) and then when browsing for files, the Finder only shows the Downloads folder. (exactly like on iOS) **Simple Finder** could kinda achieve that but it takes away several other useful features that the regular Finder offers. Again, as stated it's all theoretical/experimental.

Comment: Ah, ok. On a side note, just ask your relative to wait for another year - Apple is already intent on making macOS like ios and is crippling it further to make it a closed system like ios.

Answer (score 1):

Any access on macOS is running with the credentials of the user owning a process, so you can't prohibit user access to e.g. `~/Documents` or `~/Library` while still allowing applications started by the same user from accessing content stored there. I've never tried but removing user access from `~/Library` most likely will even prevent the user from logging in (in a probably unpleasant way).

This is vastly different from sandboxing on iOS where each app basically has it's own sandboxed space within the filesystem (which ensures that app A can't access data of app B unless both are coded specifically to support this) and where app-specific preferences etc are stored within the sandbox itself.

Comment: I see, so basically if I need to read/write in it (through normal app usage etc.), that automatically means I can browse and have access to it through a file browser. I cannot imitate iOS reading/writing to files/directories that one cannot browse/look into (whether sandboxed or not)?

Comment: @alaska_penguin_9898 You can't imitate iOS sandboxing. You can prevent users from accessing certain folders but then it applies to any kind of access.

Comment: Thank you, that was very informative. Off the top of your head, can you think of any other solution, (other than the file permissions approach that I thought of)? **Simple Finder** could achive that to a certain extent, but even that feature was discontinued as of macOS Catalina iirc.

Comment: @alaska_penguin_9898 Even Simple Finder can‘t stop you from accessing whatever you want via the applications you are allowed to run.